# lim sup of sequence of numbers vs lim sup of sequence of sets?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(a_n) = (1, -1, \frac{1}{2}, 1, -1, \frac{1}{3}, 1, -1, \frac{1}{4}, ...)$

Then $\limsup (a_n) = \inf_n \sup_{k \geq n} (a_n)$

Which in this case is $1.$

However couldn't $(a_n$) be viewed as a sequence of one element sets in which case:

$\limsup (a_n) = \bigcap_n\bigcup_{k=n} a_n$

And this means $x \in a_n$ such that $x$ occurs infinitely often. Which in this case would be: $-1, 1$.

Someone correct my understanding of this and explain the difference between the lim sup of a sequence of numbers vs the lim sup of a sequence of sets.

Comment: It's rather the other way round. Consider the sequence of characteristic functions of the $A_n$, then the characteristic function of the $\limsup$ resp. $\liminf$ is the $\limsup$ resp. $\liminf$ of the sequence of characteristic functions, $$\chi_{\limsup A_n}(x) = \limsup \chi_{A_n}(x).$$

Comment: "However couldn't (an) be viewed as a sequence of one element sets" No it couldn't.

Comment: Came here to ask this question - how can I revive it/entice a more thorough answer?